# Magento 2: Could not map class in code-migration Tool

Tags: magento2, proxy, code-migration

When using the Magento Inc. provided [code migration tool](https://github.com/magento/code-migration), there's a number of mapping files that need to be generated.  One of those is a class dependency map.   Per the `README.md`, you can generate this map with the following.

```
php bin/utils.php generateClassDependency m1
```

However, when I do this, there's about 554 lines at the end of the (long) run that read something like this

```
[2017-06-12 17:19:10][WARNING]: Could not map class: Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule
[2017-06-12 17:19:10][WARNING]: Could not map class: Mage_Cron_Model_Observer
```

Each one references a different class.  Is this expected?  Or is it an error? What would I need to do to get rid of these in a safe way (i.e. down voting anyone who tells me to comment out the warning :) )

The warning seems to come from the `Magento\Migration\Mapping\ClassMapping` class.  It's unclear if the developer of the `generateClassDependency` command decided these warnings were acceptable, or if they're really a problem.  This lack of clarity is further exacerbated by there being no clear explanation of what this command is meant to do, or how its output is ultimately used by the migration commands.  Finally, just for lolz, the `Magento\Migration\Mapping\ClassMapping` is actually an auto-generated `Magento\Migration\Mapping\ClassMapping\Proxy` class in the `generateClassDependency` command which means its constructor gets skipped/delayed.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this @Alan Storm? I have the same problem.

Comment: @ehannes My apologies, but I don't think I ever figured out how this was supposed to work.

Comment: Too sad the toolkit is unmaintained and broken. Did you do the migration manually instead?

Comment: @ehannes I used the exported code from the migration tool (with its defaults), the unirgy conversion tool (https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2), and manually combined stuff together.